# How to set kendo UI grid width

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am facing a problem with the Kendo Grid width. I want the grid to stretch to fit the content of the grid. This grid which I am working on is created dynamically, so at times it may have just 2 columns and at times it may have max 5 columns. I don't want the grid to expand and take the whole page for showing just two columns.

To get this working I added the following  css

```
.k-grid table{
    display: inline;
}
```

The problem is that when this style is applied, it completely messes up the column header and column alignment. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually this is really simple. But I wasted lot of time cause I did not get the correct source. You just need to implement following things.

Make the grid `sortable: false`

and use this CSS

```
#gridId table {
    width: auto;
}
```

But with this you loose the scrolling feature. But you can wrap your kendo grid  in another container and implement your own scrolling.

Comment: I'm almost certain you meant to say `scrollable: false`

Answer (score 3):

```
var grid = $("#kendoGridName");
grid.width(400);
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than trying to apply some css you could use some jQuery to perform this task. I do something similar in terms of height. So maybe something like this would work for you (I have modified this to do height and width).

```
function resizeGrid(size) {

    if (size === null || size === undefined) {
        size = 0.6;
    }

    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();
    windowHeight = windowHeight * size;
    windowWidth = windowWidth * size; 
    $(".k-grid-content").height(windowHeight)
    $(".k-grid).width(windowWidth);
}
```

so all this function does is scale the grid based on the current window size so for example if you want the grid to take up all the available space ie max height and width you would call `resizeGrid(1)` if you wanted it smaller say to take 50% of the screen size then you would use `reszieGrid(0.5)` if no value is used then the function just goes with a default of 60% of the available width/height.

so you could call this after your initialization of the grid and then scale the grid to an appropriate size.

by targeting the kendo css classes it makes this function easier to reuse.

if you need more info let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the solution @David. It works really well. But my problem is that I do not want to mention the width explicitly for the grid. Only thing I want is to span the grid based on the number of columns and the content it has. That is the reason I specified the display property.  To get this done in angular and pure html table is really easy, the problem starts when kendo grid comes in picture.

Comment: Well kendo supports angular as a first party citizen. Sorry I'm not to up on Angular. You could modify this code to be fired within the databound event and then adjust it based on number of columns.

Comment: Agreed, but still mentioning width of the column does not make sense as this is a dynamic grid and I dont know what content I would get from the server in terms of length. The only problem I see in the CSS which I applied is that, the style is applied to the header and content tables. When the text in the `th` is larger than the text in the `td` it messes up the alignment. I will try to give a shot with setting the width based on the number of columns and see how it goes.

Comment: if you can provide an example of how you want it to look without using kendo then I can see what I can come up with for you.

Comment: Its actually really simple without any css or explicit widths/heights. still I created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sxh7yfsL/1/).
You will see two tables spanning themselves based on the grid content. That's what I want from kendo grid

Comment: not perfect but I think this may be closer to what you want. http://dojo.telerik.com/elEwE the issue is going to be that the css from kendo is going to have to be overridden to get your desired effect.